# Recommend good kits to Newbie

Tags: arduino

I have $50 to spend on an arduino hardware. I've looked around at some intersting kits.
I found a kit that might be what I want, http://www.sainsmart.com/sainsmart-mega2560-board-3-5-tft-lcd-module-display-shield-kit-for-atmel-atmega-avr-16au-atmega8u2.html

So far that costs $55. Are there any better offer or combination?

I have some motors with gear boxes and potentiometers that I used for school projects which I can recycle.

I know that I'll need resistors but I don't know how many of which resistances.

Is there anything else alike sensors etc. that I might need or you think would be fun or good to learn with?

I dont mind extending the budget if I have to.

Comment: $50 is not much when you want to do 'everything', so what is your (main) interest? Could for instance be be robotics, sensors, wireless, audio, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out what you want, maybe by looking around at stackexchange and see which questions get your attention. After you narrowed down what you want to do (now), check the [shield list for arduino](http://shieldlist.org/) to find something appropriate to build upon.